# Untarring in python, interactive vs script call

Tags: python

I am trying to untar a tar file via `popen` (`from platform import popen`) and am running into problems.  The command runs if I use the interactive script, but does not if I put it in a .py file and run it.

Basically, I change to to that directory and run `popen("tar xvf the_tar.tar")`

Why would these be different?  How come it does not run in the script?  Identical code between the interactive session and the script!

Edit:

The exact script is as follows

```
import os, time
from platform import popen

os.chdir("C:/testing/")
popen("tar -xvf the_tar.tar")
```

Comment: On a related noted which is the version of Python you are using ? The documentation of os.popen mentions that its usage is deprecated since v2.6 and one should use the 'subprocess' module instead.

Comment: Allthough the deprecation note is correct, with regard to the question Python 2.7.1 and Python 3.1.3 at least work with the solution shown in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `tarfile` library:

```
from tarfile import TarFile

tar = TarFile("the_tar.tar")
tar.extractall()
```

Comment: This works, but why is it required instead of just calling the 'tar' process?

Comment: @kvm it's not required, but it's more convenient (see the headaches you already have with popen :) )

Comment: @kvm using the tarfile module will make your code portable. The code you write will run on any platform(machine) on which python is available immaterial of whether the machine has tar utility installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Given your info I can't see the problems you see. Probably a bit more of context. I.e. the exact script that does not work, please.

I built a sample tar archive with an empty text file in it.
Then I typed a two line python script inside this folder:

```
from platform import popen
popen("tar xvf the_tar.tar")
```

As I ran it, it gave me:

```
x sample.txt
```

as expected.
The error must happen inside your script. As with the now shown script in the question 
this also runs on my mac when I change the `os.chdir()` argument to a for me appropriate `"./"`.

Could you test it modified to `os.chdir("./")` on your machine (windows I guess)?

Comment: I have added the exact script to the question